# Directory structure for parallel development: Dart and Javascript

Tags: javascript, dart

### Project I'm working on

I am starting a webaudio project in a team in which we are making audio effects, audio visualization and audio synthesis. We are now designing a basic folder structure. Each of us is thinking of a structure and in our next meeting we will choose the best one. One of the team-members is really experienced with Javascript, but I'm leaning more to Dart, cause it just feels more familiar and robust. I have a Java background, but I'm not really experienced with web development. Therefore I want to develop the software in both languages: Dart and Javascript, so that I can eventually get to a solid decision whether it is better to use Dart or Javascript for this project.

### Directory structure?

I want to subdivide the dart libraries in three main directories: effects, visualization and synthesis. But I don't know yet where to place those main directories. According to the [Pub Package Layout Convention](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) the libraries should be located in the *lib* directory. But since all libraries will strongly depend on the webaudio API, it will only run in a browser, and thus be web application. So my **first question** is: "*Should I place my libraries in the package/libs directory or somewhere in the package/web directory?*" And "*Should I put the javascript counterparts in the same directory?*" For example: both oscillator.js and oscillator.js in the synthesis folder.

### Switch between Javascript and Dart?

Once that the directory structure is done I would like to be able to easily switch from the Dart version to the Javascript version and vice-versa, and since I need a browser with an embedded Dart VM that will be Dartium. So here goes my **second question**: "*What would be the best way to easily switch between the Javascript and the Dart version*?"

Thanks in advance!

PS: I know that I could just use the generated Javascript from dart2js, but I want actually readable Javascript. And the dart2js Javascript does not exactly meet that requirement. Furthermore I want to have good understanding on the differences between the two languages, and I think that the best way is to try them both.

**Edit**: I would like to clarify the idea of switching between Javascript and Dart on Günter's demand. I will make a Javascript port of every Dart file manually, just so that I can learn both. Since I will be developing both of them at the same time, I want to be able to test the site with the Dart version, but also with the Javascript version. So I want the HTML to load this if in Dartium:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
```

But this if in any other browser:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

I reccon that dart.js in the browser package does this to switch between *.dart and *.dart.js, depending on if the browser has a Dart VM or not. But I want it to switch between *.dart and *.js (my own js), without having to make two separate html files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: All in `lib/` except entry points is fine.

Question 2: You can use [pub serve](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-serve.html). This allows to access to the app from Dartium or any browser from the same url. Any update in a dart file will be compiled when a `*.dart.js` file is request instead of a `*.dart` file.

For your edit: you can have a look at the [dart_to_js_script_rewriter package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter) to do a transformer that will rewrite your `<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>` to `<script src="main.js"></script>`. Switching from JS to Dart will be done by adding/removing your created transformer to `pubspec.yaml` and restarting `pub serve` or `pub build`.

Comment: I know that that the pub package manager uses dart2js when using the serve command, but the point is that I want to not switch between Dart and generated Javascript, but to switch between Dart and my handwritten Javascript. As a matter of fact, if it was possible I wouldnt even want pub serve to make the *.dart.js files. I reccon that that is possible with the [--no-dart2js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386070/turn-off-dart2js-during-pub-build) flag.

Comment: I have troubles figuring out what you actually mean by switching between Dart and JS. There is ongoing work to generate readable JS from Dart https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler. I haven't tried it since a while. It's not production ready yet, but it should be usable.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin Thankyou! This does exactly what I want. I will leave the answer un-accepted for a while for if somebody has an even better solution.